# Most efficient way to keep track of a list of numbers selected by users using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, row, selection

Let's say users can choose **any** amount of numbers from a list of 1 - 300, and we need to keep track of each user's choices.  Remember, they can choose up to 300 numbers (e.g.if they choose all of them, 1, 2, 3 ... 299, 300), none at all, or something in between (e.g. 4, 17, 87, 113, 189, 251, 289).

What is the best, most efficient way to keep track of each users selection in MySQL?

The two alternatives I can think of are:

1) **One row for each user**, with a column containing a comma-separated list of their selection.  Adding and removing selections requires getting that user's column, adding/removing the selection, and then saving the list back to the column.

and

2) **One row for each individual selection**, with a column for the user it corresponds to and another column for the individual selection made.  Adding and removing selections requires simply doing an INSERT or a DELETE of the row corresponding to that user and selection.

Well, 2) seems to be more "natural" for the DB, but it *almost* seems inefficient when you have hundreds of thousands of users each making up to 300 selections, which would create a Table with a number of rows equal to the product of those two.  Whereas 1) would only contain the number of rows equivalent to the number users.

That said, I'm leaning towards 2) since it's more natural for the DB, but I just wanted to make sure it's the correct option and there is no more efficient way of doing this, since I don't want my site to slow down because of this as it gets bigger and bigger.

Thanks!

Comment: Do not work on pre-optimizations. So just take solution 2, if needed you can always add caching etc. to get a faster solution if needed.

Comment: You should not only consider the "efficiency" but also what do you want to do based on that data. Do you need to calculate with it; are those entries pure numbers or is there any metadata bound to them…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properly indexed #2 is better if anything due to the sparsely populated nature of #1 from a memory/disk perspective.  Also, 1 or 300 rows per user means little to indexed lookups where you are performing the search in logrithmic time.

Answer (score 0):

SQL is very efficient at handling rows of data, it is much less efficient at querying data within one column.